# Archive Tams using Graph Api MethodNotAllowed (405)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I create an Azure Active Directory (AAD) group, and then based on that group, a Teams team is created, all using the Graph API, and it works fine.

But when I try to call the method to archive that Teams team, I receive an error message back.

REST_Archive_Teams - Request Url:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/645428b1-a6df-47************/archive

Response Code:

MethodNotAllowed (405)

Log

Request Start

Request-Url:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/645428b1-a6df-************/archive

Request-Header:

Authorization: Bearer *****

Request-Body:

Request End

Response Start

Response-Code:

MethodNotAllowed (405)

Response-Body: {"error":{"code":"UnknownError","message":"","innerError":{"date":"2023-07-13T07:50:45","request-id":"02de4a20-4690-4ba3-8882-a0740a8a3de1","client-request-id":"02de4a20-4690-4ba3-8882-a0740a8a3de1"}}}

Response-Header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000

request-id: 02de4a20-4690-4ba3-8882-a0740a8a3de1

client-request-id: 02de4a20-4690-4ba3-8882-a0740a8a3de1 x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West Europe","Slice":"E","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AM1PEPF00024186"}}

Date: Thu, 13 Jul 2023 07:50:44 GMT

Response End

Api permissions:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error `MethodNotAllowed (405)` happens when you use incorrect HTTP method like GET instead of POST. Archive team requires POST.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/645428b1-a6df-47************/archive
```

Comment: Thank you, yes i made a basic mistake. I did not change the method to POST, only the Get method from another responce remained. Time for some free time, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP status code 405 Method Not Allowed-  response status code indicates that the server knows the request method, but the target resource doesn't support this HTTP verb.

This API method is a POST method,
`POST /teams/{id}/archive`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-archive?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request